# What is the best way to modify Admin Panel on Wordpress?

Tags: customization, custom-field, admin

I need to customize fields in my admin panel so that the user can edit content such as text style, image uploads, google analytics and such on different pages of the custom theme I have created.

Thanks in a advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Unfortunately, as it is, your question is way to broad to answer in our format. The Codes has a nice tutorial that will help you create option pages for your theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin called White Label CMS https://wordpress.org/plugins/white-label-cms/

I'm not sure if it can do everything you're looking for, but it's a start.